# Does pop throw an exception or not?

Tags: collections, concurrency, clojure

The doc for the `pop` function says that:

```
user> (doc pop)
-------------------------
clojure.core/pop
([coll])
  For a list or queue, returns a new list/queue without the first
  item, for a vector, returns a new vector without the last item. If
  the collection is empty, throws an exception.
```

However I can't seem to reproduce the behavior where an exception should be thrown.

For example here I add three elements to the queue then `pop` five times: according to the doc this shouldn't work.  However, instead of having an exception, I get nil.

```
(peek (pop (pop (pop (pop (pop (conj (conj (conj clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY 4) 5) 6)))))))
```

Now I like a lot that instead an empty queue is returned instead of throwing an exception when trying to `pop` from the empty queue but I'd like to understand why the behavior differs from the doc (at least from what I understand from reading the docs).

Basically I'd like to know if I should "protect" myself from an exception here or if I can safely assume that `pop`'ing an empty queue shall always return an empty queue (which would contradict the doc).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there does appear to be a contradiction in the doc string. Currently, popping an empty queue gives an empty queue. It would appear the core developers were debating the desired behavior judging by the comments in [the source of PersistentQueue](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentQueue.java):

```java
public PersistentQueue pop(){
    if(f == null) //hmmm... pop of empty queue -> empty queue?
        return this;
    //throw new IllegalStateException("popping empty queue");
    ISeq f1 = f.next();
    PersistentVector r1 = r;
    if(f1 == null)
        {
        f1 = RT.seq(r);
        r1 = null;
        }
    return new PersistentQueue(meta(), cnt - 1, f1, r1);
}
```

I wouldn't consider myself safe assuming this behavior will never be changed in the future.

Comment: so if I want to take a defensive measure could I write, say, a *safe-pop* function that would use *try* / *catch* under the hood and return nil if an exception is thrown?

Comment: I don't know about trying to catch an exception that doesn't exist yet (and may never). I'd probably be more inclined to test for empty myself and either throw exceptions or return nil as I saw fit.